# Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\frac{-nx^{2}}{2}}f(x) \ \mathrm dx $

Tags: real-analysis

> Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\frac{-nx^{2}}{2}}f(x) \ \mathrm dx $
>
> where $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

I have no clue how to do it... Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Use the variable substitution $y=\sqrt{n}x$ and a convergence theorem.

Comment: Or the standard approximation-to-the-identity argument will work.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Iread about two convergence theorems (dominated and monotone). I have no background in measure theory so this might be hard for me. The statement of the theorem assumes that the subset of integration is fixed. When I do the change of var, I get the bounds $\sqrt{N}$ and $-\sqrt{N}$. Do I get over it by wrtitng it as $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}f(\frac{u}{\sqrt{N}}) 1_{[-\sqrt{N},\sqrt{N}]} dx $?

Comment: @mich95: Try Dominated convergence with a bounding function given by $\|f\|_{\infty} e^{-u^2/2}$.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks, I am trying that! But in the comment above I describe a small issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the hints, by letting $t=\sqrt{n}x$, we have that
$$\sqrt{n} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\frac{-nx^{2}}{2}}f(x) \ dx=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}f\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)I_{[-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]}(t)\ dt$$
Now for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$F_n(t):=e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}f\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)I_{[-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]}(t)\to F(t):=e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}f(0)$$
and 
$$|F_n(t)|\leq Me^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$$
where $M=\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)|$.

Since $Me^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_n(t) \ dt\to \int_{\mathbb{R}}F(t) \ dt=f(0)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\ dt=f(0)\cdot \sqrt{2\pi}.$$

Comment: Exactly what I tried!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, the integrand is also continuous on $[-1,1]$. By mean-value theorem there is some $c \in [-1,1]$ such that the integral $= 2\exp (-nc^{2}/2)f(c)$, where $2$ is the length of the interval. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: For each $n$ you have that $\sqrt{n}\int\cdot=\sqrt{n}2\exp (-nc_n^{2}/2)f(c_n)$ with $c_n\in[-1,1]$. Now what happens to the bounded sequence $c_n$?