# Question about change of variables in limits of integrals using dominated convergence

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Hello my question is really inspired by the following example, but also many others which are similar. [Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\frac{-nx^{2}}{2}}f(x) \ \mathrm dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881944/compute-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-int-11-e-frac-nx2)

> Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\frac{-nx^{2}}{2}}f(x) \ \mathrm dx $
>
> where $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

When we have a limit of an integral to compute, and we change variables to get it to a more tractable form, and the change of variables is a function of n and x, say here its $t= \sqrt{n} x$, thereby eliminating the $nx^2$ from that term and sort of covering it by t, and then we take the limit of the whole function as $ n\to \infty$, aren't we assuming t is independent of n when it is dependent on n?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Upon enforcing the substitution $\displaystyle t=\sqrt n x$, for $\displaystyle  x\in [-1,1]$, $\displaystyle  t\in [-\sqrt n,\sqrt n]$ becomes a "dummy" index that spans $[-\sqrt n,\sqrt n]$.
>
> **It is, therefore, not dependent on $n$, but rather it spans a domain that depends on $\displaystyle  n$.**

Proceeding, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-\frac12nx^2}f(x)\,dx&=\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n} e^{-\frac12t^2}f(t/\sqrt n)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2}f(t/\sqrt n))\xi_{[-\sqrt n,\sqrt n]}(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $f\in C[-1,1]$, it is bounded there.  Then, we have

$$\left|e^{-\frac12t^2}f(t/\sqrt n))\xi_{[-\sqrt n,\sqrt n]}(t)\right|\le ||f||_{\infty}e^{-\frac12 t^2}\in L^1$$

where $||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in [-1,1]}|f(x)|$.

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-\frac12nx^2}f(x)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(e^{-\frac12t^2}f(t/\sqrt n))\xi_{[\sqrt n,\sqrt n]}(t)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=f(0)\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi }f(0)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is informative, I am wondering on a couple of things though, first of all, how exactly is the continuity used? Is that because otherwise supremum of f might be infinite? If we were instead told f is bounded would the result have been the same?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Continuity permits us to write $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t/\sqrt n)=f(0)$ along with assuring that $f$ attains a maximum on a closed bounded interval.

Comment: ah yes! thank you, so if we had simply that f is bounded we would have to leave it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t/\sqrt n)$ which may or may not exist in that case? And I will upvote soon!

Comment: Yes, if $f$ had a jump discontinuity at $0$, for example, then the limt would not be $f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i upvoted!

Comment: Thank you.  Much appreciative.  And feel free to best vote/accept as you see fit.